# Keras with CNTK backend: Writing custom layers

Tags: python, keras, cntk

I'm trying to write a custom layer in Keras to replicate on particular architecture proposed in a paper. The layer has no trainable weights. I believe this might be relevant, since it wouldn't be necessary to extend the class Layer.

I'm using the CNTK backend, but I'm trying to keep the code as backend-agnostic as possible, so I'm relying on the interfaces defined in keras.backend, instead of directly using CNTK.

Right now I'm just trying to get a small example to work. The example is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.misc import imread
from keras import backend as K

im = imread('test.bmp')

#I'm extending a grayscale image to behave as a color image
ex_im = np.empty([im.shape[0],im.shape[1],3])

ex_im[:,:,0] = im
ex_im[:,:,1] = im
ex_im[:,:,2] = im

conv_filter = K.ones([3,3,ex_im.shape[2],ex_im.shape[2]])
x = K.conv2d(ex_im,conv_filter,padding='same')
```

This code, however, results in the following error:

> RuntimeError: Convolution currently requires the main operand to have
>   dynamic axes

CNTK requires the input to the convolution to have dynamic axes, otherwise it would interpret the first dimension of the input as the batch size. So I tried to make the axes dynamic with placeholders (the only way I could find of doing so):

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.misc import imread
from keras import backend as K

im = imread('test.bmp')

ex_im = np.empty([1,im.shape[0],im.shape[1],3])

ex_im[0,:,:,0] = im
ex_im[0,:,:,1] = im
ex_im[0,:,:,2] = im

place = K.placeholder(shape=((None,) + ex_im.shape[1:]))

conv_filter = K.ones([3,3,ex_im.shape[3],ex_im.shape[3]])
x = K.conv2d(place,conv_filter,padding='same')
```

The image is now an array of images, with what is basically a batch size of 1.

This works correctly. However, I can't figure out how to feed an input to the placeholder in order to test my code. `eval()` doesn't take any arguments, and there doesn't seem to be a way to pass the input as an argument to the evaluation.

Is there a way to do this without placeholders? Or a way to feed the inputs to the placeholder? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong and should be following another path?

I should add that I really want to avoid being locked in to a backend, so any solutions should be backend-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using custom layers, you don't define tensors, let Keras do it for you. Just create the layer, and what will be given to the layer will already be a proper tensor:

```
images = np.ones((1,50,50,3))

def myFunc(x):
    conv_filter = K.ones([3,3,3,3])
    return K.conv2d(x,conv_filter,padding='same')

inp = Input((50,50,3))
out = Lambda(myFunc, output_shape=(50,50,3))(inp)

model = Model(inp,out)
print(model.predict(images))
```

Comment: Simply using place = K.variable(ex_im) still results in the same RuntimeError as I mentioned in the original post. Am I missing something?

Comment: This answer does what I needed, thank you. To those coming across this question in the future: I needed this in order to test some code I was developing. This layers will be integrated into an existing model, so there will be no need to create a separate model just for these layers.